# How to implement a class with several generic parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Here is my Java class. How can I write it on Kotlin?

```
public class TargetTitleEntryController extends BaseController {

    public interface TargetTitleEntryControllerListener {
        void onTitlePicked(String option);
    }

    public <T extends Controller & TargetTitleEntryControllerListener> TargetTitleEntryController(T targetController) {
        setTargetController(targetController);
    }

    public TargetTitleEntryController() { }
}
```

Comment: [Generics: in, out, where - Kotlin Programming Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).

Comment: I did it this way
`class SecondController<T> where T: Controller, T: SecondController.SecondControllerListener`
but only I didn’t succeed in inheriting from the Controller class

Comment: Your Java class isn't generic so don't make your Kotlin class generic. Instead you have a generic _method_ so what you need in Kotlin is a generic function (described in the page I linked to). The _Kotlin Reference_ also covers how to write classes and specify inheritance—see all the links on the left of the page.

Comment: I did it this way `class SecondController<T> : Controller() where T: Controller, T: SecondController.SecondControllerListener`

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way `class SecondController<T> : Controller() where T: Controller, T: SecondController.SecondControllerListener`